# MPMoviePlayerViewController not working in full screen in both orentation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am working on `MPMoviePlayerViewController` but struggling with playing video in full screen when changing orientation.

I have recorded video in landscape so it is possible to play that video in portrait in full screen.

[image]

Check this image for reference where video is in landscape and it should play red rectangle part when device is in portrait in full screen.

(the rectangle part contains the center of video and not the entire video).

so if anybody know's solution please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: it'd be best if you posted your code. note also that if you're developing for iOS9+, apple recommends to use AVPlayerViewController

Comment: Thanks for your replay.

Is it possible to do as i said in question if i use AVPlayer?

Comment: there definitely is, though I dont doubt that it's also possible for MPMoviePlayer. but the point is that without posting code, it's more difficult to help you

Comment: Did you set the `scalingMode` to `MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill`?